# Should my SinglyLinkedList's delete() and update() methods show anything when user press the respective numbers?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainSinglyLinkedList{ 

   public static void main(String[] args){ 
     
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
     int choice;
   
    SinglyLinkedList sll = new SinglyLinkedList();
   
     Listing l1  = new Listing("Carol",    4354,  3.2);
     Listing l2  = new Listing("Timothy",  2353,  4.0);
     Listing l3  = new Listing("Dean",     4544,  2.4);
     Listing l4  = new Listing("Sue",      3445,  3.0);
   
  sll.insert(l2); 
  sll.insert(l3); 
  sll.insert(l4); 
  
   
   do
   { 

       // a user can choose between different operations by pressing a number 

      System.out.println("*****************(Menu Operations:)******************"); 
   

      System.out.println("(Press 1). Insert a new student's information."); 
      System.out.println("(Press 2). Fetch a student's information"); 
      System.out.println("(Press 3). Delete a student's information"); 
      System.out.println("(Press 4). Update a student's information"); 
      System.out.println("(Press 5). Output all the student's information."); 
      System.out.println("(Press 6). Exit the program."); 
      System.out.println("Enter your choice."); 
      choice = scan.nextInt(); 
      switch(choice)
      { 
        case 1: 
             System.out.println("Are students inserted: " +  sll.insert(l1));   
           break; 
        case 2:
         System.out.println("The student's information that's outputted:" + sll.fetch("Dean"));
           break;
         case 3:
           sll.delete("Carol");
           break;
        case 4:
             sll.update("Carol", l2);
             break;
        case 5: System.out.println("All the student's information: ");
          sll.showAll();
      }
     



  }while(choice!=6); 
} 

}
```

```html
public class SinglyLinkedList{
    private Node h; 
   public SinglyLinkedList()
   { 
       h = new Node(); // list header
       h.l = null; 
       h.next = null; // dummy node
    } 

   public boolean insert(Listing newListing)
   {
      Node n = new Node();
      if(n == null)
        return false;
      else
       { 
          n.next = h.next;     
          h.next = n;       
          n.l = newListing.deepCopy();
          return true; 
       } 
    } 

   public Listing fetch(String targetKey)
   { 

      Node p = h.next; 
      while(p != null && !(p.l.compareTo(targetKey) == 0))
      { 
         p = p.next;  
      } 
      if(p != null) 
        return p.l.deepCopy(); 
      else 
       return null; 
  }

  public boolean delete(String targetKey) 
  { 
     Node q = h; 
     Node p= h.next; 
     while(p != null && !(p.l.compareTo(targetKey)==0))
     { 
       q = p; 
       p = p.next;    
     }
     if(p != null)
     { 
        q.next = p.next; 
        return true;
     } 
     else 
      return false; 
  } 
  public boolean update(String targetKey, Listing newListing)
  { 
     if(delete(targetKey) == false) 
        return false;
     else if(insert(newListing) == false)
        return false;
       return true;
   }
  public void showAll()
  { 
    Node p = h.next; 
    while(p != null)
    { 
      System.out.println(p.l.toString());
      p = p.next; 
    } 
  } 
  public class Node
  { 
    private Listing l; 
    private Node next; 
    public Node()
    { 

    } 
  } 


}
```

Hello All, 
I got my SinglyLinkedList and MainSinglyLinkedList application to compile correctly, but my only problem is should my SinglyLinkedList's delete() and update() methods show something  when the user press the respective numbers in the do while loop? I know these methods are working  internally because of my output() method doesn't output one student. Any suggestions? Here is my just my *SinglyLinkedList* and *MainSinglyLinkedList* applications.

Comment: What do you think it should display?  What does the assignment say you need to display?  These are not questions we can answer "correctly", you need to make the code match the requirements, and if the requirements are unclear go to the person that wrote the requirements (this is how it works in the real world).  You _could_ display a confirmation message ("Item deleted", for instance) but that would be the responsibility of the user-interface code, not the `SinglyLinkedList` code.

Comment: @Jim Garrison The assignment doesn't say anything about displaying it for those two methods. But it's just weird for a nonprogrammer to press a number and literally nothing happens. I am not stupid; that's a legitimate question that shouldn't be overlooked.

Comment: No, it's an **excellent** question ***to ask the provider of the requirements***.  There is no "right" answer that we can provide, and that will be useful for future readers of this site.  IMO a confirmation message could be totally appropriate but, in a real-world situation I would clarify with the project owner what was appropriate.  There may be legitimate reasons why a confirmation message would get in the way, for example if the API was intended to be driven by another program that was expecting silence on success and only wanted to see a message on failure.